# Using wildcard for files with jq on Windows

Tags: windows, cmd, jq

I am using jq 1.6 on Windows 8.1 and facing same issue as reported here
https://github.com/stedolan/jq/issues/1644

Command as simple as `jq . *.json` is failing with following error:

> Assertion failed!
>
> Program: jq.exe
>   File: src/main.c, Line 256
>   Expression: wargc == argc
>
> This application has requested the Runtime
>   to terminate it in an unusual way. Please contact the application's
>   support team for more information.

Does anyone have solution to this? What is the correct way to use `jq` with all the files in the folder on windows?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a curious problem.

As alredy [answered by peak](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53388391/2861476), `cmd.exe` does not expand wildcards, leaving this work to the programs. And `jq` does not handle wildcards (from the issues list, more later).

But this is not the full reason for this failure.

As the question points, source code fails in an assert: `wargc == argc`. When reading the source code, in windows `jq` tries to process the original command line with

```
 wchar_t **wargv = CommandLineToArgvW(GetCommandLineW(), &wargc);
```

trying to retrieve the equivalent to `argv[]` and `argc` but handling multibyte arguments.

As `cmd` is not expanding the wildcard there will be three arguments (command line in question)

```
jq  .  *.json
^^  ^  ^....^  
0   1  2
```

both in `argv[]` and `wargv[]`, so `argc` and `wargc` should match.

Then, why does it fail? Why `argc` is different to `wargc`?

Because GCC was used to compile the program.

And no, the problem is not GCC itself. The "problem" is that the argument handling in GCC runtime DOES expand the wildcard (Microsoft compiler runtime does not, but it doesn't matter as it will also not solve the problem).

That means that `argc` and `argv` (determined by GCC code with wildcard expansion) will contain information according to the number of files matching the wildcard while `wargc` and `wargv` (determined by MS code without wildcard expansion) will not.

A simple way to probe it is to have only one `.json` file when trying the previous command. The assert will not fail but `jq` will fail with `jq: error: Could not open file *.json: Invalid argument` as it does not handle wildcards.

```
jq . test.json       As seen in argv   argc  = 3
jq . *.json          As seen in wargv  wargc = 3
```

So, how to deal with it? Without modifying the `jq`'s source code your best option is to concatenate the list of files and pass it to `jq`. [References](https://superuser.com/q/460598) in peak's answer and in your comment should deal with the problem.

But remember that in `cmd` and batch files your command lines are limited to 8191 characters. If it is not enough to deal with your problem you can try with something like (yes, a lot of lines, most of them comments and command usage)

```cmd
@if (@this==@isBatch) @then /* ------------------------------------- batch code
@echo off
    setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion

    rem This is an hybrid batch/javascript file. The batch part will retrieve
    rem the required information and start the cscript engine to execute the 
    rem javascript part of this file.

    rem Retrieve a safe reference to current batch file 
    call :getCurrentFile thisFile fileName

    rem Arguments to current batch file are the command line to execute later
    rem Using an environment variable to avoid losing quotes when using the
    rem internal Wscript argumeng handling routines
    set [commandLine]=%*

    if not defined [commandLine] (
        echo(
        echo usage: command1 ^| "%fileName%" command2
        echo(
        echo where:
        echo     command1   is a command generating a set of lines that will be
        echo                concatenated to pass as arguments to command2
        echo(
        echo     command2   is the command to execute with all the lines from 
        echo                command1 as command line arguments
        echo(
        echo examples:
        echo(
        echo    dir /b ^| "%fileName%" cmd /c echo
        echo    dir /b *.json ^| "%fileName%" jq . 
        echo(
        goto :eof
    )

    rem Execute the javascript part of this script
    "%windir%\system32\cscript.exe" //nologo //e:JScript "%thisFile%" 
    goto :eof


:getCurrentFile fullPath fileName
    set "%~1=%~f0"
    set "%~2=%~nx0"
    goto :eof

------------------------------------------------------------- end of batch code
*/@end //------------------------------------------------------ javascript code

/*
    This script will read all lines from standard input and execute the 
    command stored by the batch code above into the [commandLine] environment 
    variable, passing as command lien arguments the concatenation of all lines 
    present in the standard input.
*/

var shell = WScript.CreateObject('WScript.Shell')
  , commandLine = shell.Environment("PROCESS").Item('[commandLine]')
  , stdIn = WScript.StdIn
  , stdOut = WScript.StdOut
  , stdErr = WScript.StdErr
  , line = ''
  , buffer = []
  ;
    // read the list of arguments from standard input
    while ( !stdIn.AtEndOfStream ){ 
        if ( 
            line = stdIn.ReadLine().replace(/"/g, '') 
        ) buffer.push( ' "' + line + '"' );
    };

    // concatenate all arguments 
    buffer = buffer.join('');

    // if we don't have a command line, output what we have contatenated 
    // but if we have a command line, execute it, get its output and show it
    // as it is possible that we are piping it to another process.

    if ( commandLine ){
        try {
            stdOut.WriteLine(
                shell.Exec( commandLine + buffer ).StdOut.ReadAll()
            );
        } catch ( e ){
            stdErr.WriteLine( 'ERROR: Command line exec failed when running:' );
            stdErr.WriteLine( '---------------------------------------------' );
            stdErr.WriteLine( commandLine + buffer );
            stdErr.WriteLine( '---------------------------------------------' );
        };
    } else {
        stdOut.WriteLine( buffer );
    };
```

Save it as a `cmd` file (ex. `list2args.cmd`) and use it as suggested

```
dir /b *.json | list2args.cmd jq .
```

The difference is that doing the concatenation inside the script part and starting the process using the `WScript.Shell.Exec` method we can use command lines up to 32KB (the windows limit for command lines).

Comment: Great.. If I want to use multiple folders then `dir /b/s` is also working with this..

Comment: @Kamal, `cmd` parser executes several pases over the command line handling the caret escaping. Try with `"\"2018-05-06 11:12:13\" | capture(\"(?^^^^^^^<Y^^^^^^^>[0-9]+)\^")"`

Comment: MD, Thanks for the reply, actually with -f option of `jq` I did not face that problem(that's why I removed the comment). I tried the cmd which you shared and  it does give expected output but also prints this error `File Not Found` before that output. Also can you explain the reason for exact 6 extra caret signs?

Comment: @Kamal, some of the carets escape the angular bracket and some escape the escape itself. Each time the line is parsed some carets are consumed as escape characters. The line is parsed when found, but as it contains a pipe a separate `cmd` instance is started to handle each side and the `cmd` in the right side parse it again. We have `^^^^` and `^^^<`. After first parse we have `^^` and `^<`. After second parse `^` and `<` that is `^<`

Comment: Using a simple powershell trick:  `powershell jq . (get-item *.json)`

Comment: Amazing explanation. For the workaround I would just install `xargs`, or better yet use WSL Bash where wildcard expansion "just works".

Answer (score 1):

As explained at https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Windows_Batch_Scripting

> "Unlike shells of some other operating systems, the cmd.exe shell does not perform wildcard expansion"

So assuming you can't simply process the files one at a time, you'll either have to
create the list of files explicitly, or use a different shell.

For further details and suggestions, see
https://superuser.com/questions/460598/is-there-any-way-to-get-the-windows-cmd-shell-to-expand-wildcard-paths

and if you’re using Windows 10:

https://www.howtogeek.com/249966/how-to-install-and-use-the-linux-bash-shell-on-windows-10/

Comment: This [https://superuser.com/a/460648] script works, and I can print file names with `echo %expanded_list%` after running the script, but how to use output of that variable with `jq`? This does not work `jq empty %expanded_list%`, but gives error like `parse error: Invalid numeric literal at line 2, column 0`

Comment: What happens when you run`jq empty FIRSTFILE` where FIRSTILE is the first filename produced by `echo %expanded_list%` ?

Comment: ok, I understood the problem from your comment, my folder had files other than .json, I updated the script to only return the .json files, and now it works. Thanks

Comment: When using in a folder containing too many files, I get error of `The input line is too long.`

Answer (score 0):

[MC ND](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2861476/mc-nd) gave an amazing explanation [why this happens](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53391756/253468).

However if you just want to make it work, I recommend using [Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install), or [Git Bash](https://gitforwindows.org/). Both of these handle wildcard expansion trivially after initial setup.

*The return on investment is great because any time you have problems with `cmd` you can just hop over to `bash` and continue.*