# How to merge multiple json files in a directory with jq or any tool?

Tags: json, jq

I am trying to merge all json files in a directory (can be many).

I know that if there are only 2 files, I can use `jq -s . file1.json file2.json`. But when I tried to use the a wild card like `jq -s . file*.json`, it fails. Any idea?

Comment: How does it fail? Any error messages?

Comment: [Mergine many json file into one](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/433678/merging-many-json-files-into-one-by-merging-it-into-a-common-object)

Answer (score 9):

Try this:

```
jq -s add *.json > merged.json
```

Answer (score 1):

**The answer**
Here is the `jq` answer... for more see the explanation below:

```
s="*.json"; jq -s "`x=-1; n=$(ls $s | wc -l); while [ $((x++)) -lt $(($n-2)) ]; do printf ".[$x] * " ; done; printf ".[$(($n-1))]";`" $s
```

**Step by step explanation**

To merge two json files using `jq` use this command:

```
jq -s ".[0] * .[1]" file1.json file2.json
```

Now to merge three json files:

```
jq -s ".[0] * .[1] * .[2]" file1.json file2.json file3.json
```

Let's follow the same logic and generalise for n files using wildcards. The difficult part is to generate the string `.[0] * .[1] ... .[n-1]`.

First let's find n. n is the number of json files in the folder. so:

```
ls *.json | wc -l
```

now let's write a loop that will build the string ".[1] * .. * .[a] * .[a+1] * .. * .[n-2] *". The kernel of this string is `.[a] *` so:

```
x=-1; n=$(ls *.json | wc -l); while [ $((x++)) -lt $(($n-2)) ]; do printf ".[$x] * " ; done;
```

ok and now let's add the last part `.[n-1]`:

```
x=-1; n=$(ls *.json | wc -l); while [ $((x++)) -lt $(($n-2)) ]; do printf ".[$x] * " ; done; printf ".[$(($n-1))]";
```

now let's pass that string to the jq command... and let's parameterise *.json so that we can replace it with whatever we want with ease:

```
s="*.json"; jq -s "`x=-1; n=$(ls $s | wc -l); while [ $((x++)) -lt $(($n-2)) ]; do printf ".[$x] * " ; done; printf ".[$(($n-1))]";`" $s
```

et voilà!

Answer (score 0):

While waiting a jq's solution, let me address the question "... or any tool?"

Different people mean different things by "merging", thus assuming here a plain recursive JSON merging, then with `jtc` (another tool) the solution would be like this (for an arbitrary number of files):

- read all the JSONs into one super JSON array
- merge into the 1st child (the first read JSON) the rest of read JSONs
- output the resulting 1st JSON child in the array

```
jtc -J / -w[0] -mi[1:] / -w[0] *.json
```

to illustrate the solution, here's how it works with couple arbitrary JSON files:

```
bash $ jtc -tc file1.json 
{
   "days": {
      "2020-05-18": { "seconds": 60 },
      "2020-05-19": { "seconds": 30 },
      "2020-05-20": { "seconds": 1400 }
   },
   "total": { "seconds": 1490 }
}
bash $ jtc -tc file2.json 
{
   "days": {
      "2020-05-20": { "seconds": 95 },
      "2020-05-21": { "seconds": 80 },
      "2020-05-22": { "seconds": 120 }
   },
   "total": { "seconds": 295 }
}
bash $ jtc -J / -w[0] -mi[1:] / -w[0] -tc file*.json
{
   "days": {
      "2020-05-18": { "seconds": 60 },
      "2020-05-19": { "seconds": 30 },
      "2020-05-20": {
         "seconds": [ 1400, 95 ]
      },
      "2020-05-21": { "seconds": 80 },
      "2020-05-22": { "seconds": 120 }
   },
   "total": {
      "seconds": [ 1490, 295 ]
   }
}
bash $
```

> `-tc` flag is used only to display JSONs here in a compact format

PS. It so happens that I'm the creator of `jtc` tool - unix JSON processing utility.

Comment: I am sorry that I did not post my question clearly. The jsons are all with the same format, just with different data. I need to run the tool on windows as our servers are all windows.

Comment: Does jtc have a windows version? I could not find it so far.

Comment: The commands of some of the "answers" from the various threads here in stackoverflow or stackexchange do not work. For example, I used command jq -s '{ attributes: map(.attributes[0]) }' *.json. But jq throws an error "This application has requested the Runtime to terminate it in an unusual way.
Please contact the application's support team for more information."

Comment: If I used the simple command "jq.exe -s . *.json", I get exactly the same error thrown by jq. Not sure if jq supports wildcard on windows platform? If I only passed 2 files, jq does work properly.

Comment: No, there's no native version of `jtc` for widows yet. But it's easily compilable under [cygwin](https://www.cygwin.com/) environment

Comment: wildcard (*) is not directly supported by end application, it's the shell's job to expand it into the list of files and supply (the list) to the end application

Comment: > I get exactly the same error thrown by jq
- why don't you post the error that you're getting? it would be easier then to help you

Comment: Here is the error: D:\work\json>jq.exe -s . *.json
Assertion failed!

Program: D:\work\json\jq.exe
File: src/main.c, Line 256

Expression: wargc == argc

This application has requested the Runtime to terminate it in an unusual way.
Please contact the application's support team for more information.

Comment: here's the answer to that error: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53387811/using-wildcard-for-files-with-jq-on-windows

Comment: Thanks, Dmitry. I will try out that cmd script.

Comment: Just tested the cmd. It runs but the json outputed is in bad format. Looks like the cmd simply appends the data in the json files together which obviously is no good.

Comment: I don't know how to show the json test files in the site as there is a character limitation

Comment: I ran the cmd as "dir /b *.json | list2args.cmd jq ." as suggested by the thread

Comment: I'd suggest you to file it as a separate question. Someone with the access to windows should be able to help you. Because now it becomes not a JSON query but rather a OS specific question.